# change whole field of html element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to change the whole field of `input` using jQuery from this

```
<input type="file" id="dok_npwp_link" class="upload required" name="dok_npwp_link" accept="image/*" />
```

to this

```
<input id ="dok_npwp_link" type="hidden" name="dok_npwp_link">
```

from what I read in jquery manual I can change type, value etc how about change the whole context of field, since I'm new to javascript I don't find the solution yet.

Comment: why would you want to do this, as adding php tag from JS will do no good to the page...

Comment: sorry mismatch php and html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `jQuery` you can change the attribute by

---

**Example:** Changing type from `hidden` to `file` and adding attribute `accept`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dok_npwp_link").attr("type", "file"); /* Changing type to file */
  $("#dok_npwp_link").attr("accept", "image/*"); /* Adding attr accept */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="dok_npwp_link" type="hidden" name="dok_npwp_link">
```

**Example:** (On reverse) Changing type from `file` to `hidden` and removing attribute `accept`

```js
$(function(){
 $("#dok_npwp_link").attr("type", "hidden"); /* Changing type to hidden */
 $("#dok_npwp_link").removeAttr("accept"); /* Removing attr accept */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="dok_npwp_link" class="upload required" name="dok_npwp_link" accept="image/*" />
```

Doc: [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Comment: What do you mean @fahmihammadi?

Comment: Basically same thing. Ill make a fiddle. One moment

Comment: i mean change the whole field in the first field `<input type="file" id="dok_npwp_link" class="upload required" name="dok_npwp_link" accept="image/*" />` the accept attribute`(accept="image/*") `if i only change the attr it only change file type to hidden type it wont change the other element
in short can i replace the whole element?

Comment: I added a fiddle on my answer. Basically, will convert `hidden` type to `file` type. And add an attribute `accept="image/*"`

Comment: thanks for the advice, i've get what i have to do base on those advice

Comment: I also added the reverse. Changing from `file` to `hidden` and removing the attr `accept`

Comment: so basically reverse is just revert the code to normal. btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

`type` and `value` are attributes on the input fields. And to change these using jQuery you can use `.attr()` method.

```js
$("#dok_npwp_link").attr({
  type: "hidden",
  value: "some value"
})

// To verify the value
console.log($("#dok_npwp_link").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="dok_npwp_link" class="upload required" name="dok_npwp_link" accept="image/*" /><br>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, i've get what i have to do base on those advice

Answer (score 0):

You can't use php code in javascript.

You can change all attributes from js or jquery.

Like this=>

```
$('input-field').attr('type',"value");
$('input-field').attr('name',"value");
$('input-field').val("value");
```

to remove attributes:

```
$('input').removeAttr('attribute-name');
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, i've get what i have to do base on those advice